# Foreach loop printing duplicate last entry with output to data file

Tags: php, foreach, fwrite

I have a foreach loop which loops through to present html and store data to a data file. The issue (which has been raised before) is that the last alliteration of the foreach loop is **duplicated**. Using **unset does not work**, as it writes the data file from within the foreach loop! How can I fix this issue? I want to cut out the duplicate and maintain writing to the data file...

My code:

```
// Save data to a DAT file
$datafile = "datfile.dat";
$fh = fopen($datafile, 'w') or die("can't open file");

foreach($xml->DROP as $shipment) {
    $CONNOTE_ID = $shipment->HEADER->BILL_OF_LADING; // 20 CHARS
    $output = sprintf("%-20.20s", $CONNOTE_ID);
    echo $output;
    unset($shipment);
    fwrite($fh, $output);
}

$output .= "%%EOF";
fwrite($fh, $output);
echo "%%EOF";
fclose($fh);
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ISHPMNT1>
<DROP>
<HEADER>
  <BILL_OF_LADING>VW038687030000006</BILL_OF_LADING>
</HEADER>
</DROP>
</ISHPMNT1>
```

Comment: What is the array returned at `$xml->DROP`?

Comment: Foreach doesn’t just “duplicate” data – your issue must be something else. Do some proper debugging, to find out what it is.

Comment: CBroe, your comments are never helpful. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29992

Comment: That bug report is about using a reference within foreach, which you are not doing. And as is also pointed out there, this is not a “bug”, but behavior that is _to be expected_ (but that you didn’t understand that either, is no real surprise).

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, your response actually helped. Fixed it! You should be able to work out where the coding has gone wrong, no need for me to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue resided with my understanding to how fwrite works. I was writing the last foreach 'output' variable twice, with the second adding %%EOF hence why it seemed like a duplicate sent through by the foreach loop.

Fixed coding section:

```
echo $output;
fwrite($fh, $output);
}
fwrite($fh, "%%EOF");
```

thanks to everyone who tried to help! Much appreciated